# Can we put php in jquery code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to use php script in jquery code. Here I put php script in my jquery but my jquery function is not working then. Is it right way to put php script in a jquery function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        var count2=1;
        $('a#addTelefono').click(function() {
            count2 +=1;

            $('<p><div style="float:left;width: 100%;"><select name="product_id[]" ><?php $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_product"); while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ echo "<option value='".$res['id']."'>".$res['product_name']."</option>";}?></select><input type="text" name="discount[]" placeholder="discount ' + count2 + '" style="margin-left: 8px;" id="discount_' + count2 + '" />%<a href="#" class="remove" id="elimina"><img src="images/cross.png"></a></div></p>').fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#extendTelefono'); 

                i++;    
                return false;           
        });
        //fadeout selected item and remove
        $('.remove').live('click', function() {
            $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function(){ 
                $(this).remove();
                return false;
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Use AJAX to get the HTML from another page, for simplicity.

Comment: If you intend to run the script on client side (what I assume you want to), it cannot work, because PHP is a server-side language, not a client-side language.

Comment: use jquery .post.. here is the link http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @Abrixas2: You are partially right. This script will work if he have this JS code inside a PHP as inline JS. If the script is placed in an external JavaScript file, with .js extension, it will not work.

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS: It should, if you put necessary steps into the script as well (like opening/closing database connections) and then get the script through the PHP interpreter.

Comment: View the **actual** HTML generated. That is your answer.

Comment: PHP inside a JS file (not parsed by PHP engine) will not execute.

Comment: yes exactly as @Abrixas2 said, suppose you are writing any php code in your javascript/jquery, then actually your file will be processed at server end and your php statements will be replaced with respective outputs and you will get the response from server without any php statement.

Comment: @pmd and @Abrixas2: Please look in to this page how PHP code in a external JS file is parsed, `http://viswalingasurya.co.in/sample01.html`. The JS file is here, `http://viswalingasurya.co.in/sample01.js`

Comment: `.js` files will not be parsed by PHP engine. If you really want to do that, either you need to place the script as inline script inside a PHP page or `.js` files must be delivered by PHP using another PHP page with proper `header`.

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS Or your server must be configured to parse every `.js` file with PHP before delivering it to the client (`AddType application/x-httpd-php .js` for Apache).

Comment: @Abrixas2: That's what I mentioned there as `(not parsed by PHP engine)` :D

Comment: You are right @ViswalingaSuryaS, but I guess we have responded as per the tags 'anurag' mentioned above i.e. 'php' & 'jquery', and this is obvious that if any one is willing to write php code in his file, that file must be a php file, not html or js file. so we are assuming that file containing the jquery code is a php file.

Comment: @pmd: The OP placed the script inside a PHP page and I understood it from his code, `<script type="text/javascript">`. With this code, it cannot be an external file. I was answering Abrixas2, for his 1st comment.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make it in two steps and separate your php code from jQuery for readability :

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_product");
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $contents .= "<option value='".$res['id']."'>".$res['product_name']."</option>";
}


$('<select name="product_id[]" ><?php echo($contents); ?></select> .....');
```

Also, be carreful of caracters you have in **$res['product_name']** : It can fail if you have a quote in your product name (so you must escape it).

Moreover, mysql_* is deprecated, see [mysqli_*](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Use console to see errors (All browser has one).

In chrome : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console
In Firefox : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Outils/Web_Console